# Postgres query on json with empty value

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a query in JSON to filter out the data based on data present inside JSON field .

Table name:  audit_rules
Column name: rule_config (json)

rule_config contains JSON which contain 'applicable_category' as an attribute in it.

Example

```json
{
   "applicable_category":[
      {
         "status":"active",
         "supported":"yes",
         "expense_type":"Meal",
         "acceptable_variation":0.18,
         "minimum_value":25.0
      },
      {
         "status":"active",
         "supported":"yes",
         "expense_type":"Car Rental",
         "acceptable_variation":0.0,
         "minimum_value":25.0
      },
      {
         "status":"active",
         "supported":"yes",
         "expense_type":"Airfare",
         "acceptable_variation":0.0,
         "minimum_value":75
      },
      {
         "status":"active",
         "supported":"yes",
         "expense_type":"Hotel",
         "acceptable_variation":0.0,
         "minimum_value":75
      }
   ],
   "minimum_required_keys":[
      "amount",
      "date",
      "merchant",
      "location"
   ],
   "value":[
      0,
      0.5
   ]
}
```

But some of the rows doesn't have any data or doesn't have the 'applicable_category' attribute in it.

So while running following query i am getting error:

```
select s.*,j from 
  audit_rules  s 
   cross join lateral json_array_elements ( s.rule_config#>'{applicable_category}' ) as j
WHERE j->>'expense_type' in ('Direct Bill');
```

> Error: SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: cannot call json_array_elements on a scalar

Comment: You tagged the question with three different, unsupported Postgres version (one of them not even supporting JSON). Which Postgres version are you **really** using?

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.6.18 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.9.3, 64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict the result to only rows that contain an array:

```
select j.*
from audit_rules  s 
   cross join lateral json_array_elements(s.rule_config#>'{applicable_category}') as j
WHERE json_typeof(s.rule_config -> 'applicable_category') = 'array'
  and j ->> 'expense_type' in ('Meal')
```